# Android activity over default lock screen using xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, lockscreen

I wanted to know how exactly i can add `WindowManager`'s `LayoutParams` flag inside C# code of **xamarin**.

For example we can do it in **Android** by code given below.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 10):

Like so:

```
namespace SampleCode
{
    [Activity (Label = "SampleCode", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn|
                WindowManagerFlags.DismissKeyguard|
                WindowManagerFlags.ShowWhenLocked|
                WindowManagerFlags.TurnScreenOn);       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: here is the edited version with some more context I guess. it's pretty much the same as Java syntax.

Comment: Thanks Alex, i will accept your answer after i tryout your solution.

Comment: Alex, i have posted similar questions for another framework, can you see if you can answer this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901440/activity-of-android-above-default-lock-screen-using-unity-c-sharp-scripts