# Activity of android above default lock screen using unity c# scripts

Tags: c#, android, unityscript, lockscreen

how i can add `WindowManager`'s `LayoutParams` flag inside unity c# scripts.

For example i can do it in **Android** by code as follow.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that like this:

`AndroidJavaObject activity = new   AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        AndroidJavaObject win = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getWindow");
        AndroidJavaObject lp = new AndroidJavaClass("android/view/WindowManager$LayoutParams");
        win.Call("addFlags",lp.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED"));
        win.Call("addFlags",lp.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON"));`

i recently doing the same thing,it's work,it float on top of the lock screen,And if the user press HOME key,he will back to the system lock screen.

note that both "/" or "." is just the same. the $ is for inner class,in this case,LayoutParams is the inner class of WindowManager.